# MySQL View is faster or not for querying from DB that containd 40 million data

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

I have a table that contains 40 million data. I want to reduce the query time. is it possible to do it using views?. if yes, could you please explain how?.

Comment: You're asking a "yes or no" question? Then the answer is "yes".

Comment: My apologize for such question can you please explain me how to reduce the query time using view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to reduce query time using view because it have clustered index assigned and they'll store temporary result that can speed up resulting queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if MySQL has clustered indices or temporary results (Oracle and SQL Server do that). MySQL views **can** use temporary tables, but not in the way you're thinking--they are only used for that query and generally allow the main table(s) to be locked for less time.

Comment: ya.. you are right... MySQL has not indexed views.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the MySQL statement for creating a view is:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT ...
```

Where the algorithm is one of MERGE, TEMPTABLE, or UNDEFINED.

However, as always the answer to how to increase performance is, "it depends". We really need more details on the table structure (columns and types), current indices, how often the table rows get updated, how often new rows get inserted, and what kind of data is stored in the table in order to make an educated guess on how to improve performance.