# MySQL database configuration for fastening the select and insert queries

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

There are several DBEngines are available for MySQL DB. Currently i'm using InnoDB. My actual problem is i have a table that consist of millions of data. Therefore the select queries that given to this table is extremely slow. i need to know which configuration should i use to make the select query faster that doesn't affects the speed of insertion.

Comment: do not ask the same question twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863546/mysql-view-is-faster-or-not-for-querying-from-db-that-containd-40-million-data. If your not getting the answer try to edit the question to make better

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. Before I also have this kind of problem ended up using master-slave replication. Master handles all inserts and slaves handles all selects. What I did is I put indexes on slaves to make the select faster. Then the master will not have any index. Except of foreign keys and primary key. Sometimes it just takes trial and error to make the database faster.

You could also try partitioning and clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Basically You should start using indexes on the table, for example if You query by name, You should index the name column. If You query by name and some number using AND clause, You should create a composite index, starting with the less costier column (number).

To find out, if indexes are missing, check the query execution plan. For details on this, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html and the subsequent chapters-

Please notice, mysql does not support ascending and descending mixed indexes (e.g. name ASC, createdate DESC), so if You have bad luck, You must fondle around with some auxiliary table.

Finally, if You have NO FOREIGN KEYS in Your table, You can consider using partitioned tables. Partitioning makes sense, when Your data can be broken into several "blocks", and if most query are able to downsize the selected data into a couple of these blocks, partitioning can speed up the query a lot. I'd refer You to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html for details on this.

On server side, check the memory configuration. If Your data amount is large, check if Your queries have ORDER BY clauses. If Yes, check if You should increase the sort buffer (otherwise db servers start sorting on disk which is slow like hell). For this, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html

Unfortunately Your request is kind of vague, applying these mechanisms always is highly specific to Your needs, but You can feel free to apply more details (e.g. table structure, slow query etc) to Your request in order to get more specific hints.

Answer (score 0):

There are GUI tools available help with this, but its a skilled and wide job. So they don't cover everything, its likely you will need to use command line stuff/sql statements etc to help. Some of the lime light I can put on to help you with is :

1. Do use query optimization(use of explain etc in mysql). To begin optimising things: Sticking "EXPLAIN" in front of select is THE way to see how a query is being executed and idetify how to improve it. Learn to interpret the output: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html You'll often be able to add new indexes/add columns to existing ones to improve things. But you will also encounter times that queries need to be restructured.
2. Make sure the MySQL Query Cache is set up and working and give it a bit more RAM
3. Make sure that your important queries aren't doing anything that prevents mysql caching them. For example, using the NOW() function in queries does this - for obvious reasons - NOW changes every second! You can instead put a timestamp into the sql, and use the time to the nearest minute/hour/day (the largest period you can get away with) to allow mysql to get some caching benefit.
4. It has to be properly normalized.
5. Cache your tables and caching is problematic with huge(like you said) amount of data in table so break your data into fragments and work on probable querying.
6. **warning** don't touch config unless you know the better of it. Overview, including config for if its not logging this already, is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html - I've also found that setting long_query_time to 0 for a day or so, so that all queries are logged here with time taken, is a useful way to get an idea of exactly where the performance is going. But I wouldn't go there immediately! And don't leave it on, the logs can get massive.

**Improvising and Enhansing tools :**

1. mysqlsla (mysql slow log analyser) from here: http://hackmysql.com/mysqlsla is a good tool.
2. http://www.maatkit.org/ is also fine tuning tool.

Comment: yea worthy, but why not this mysql user switch to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

For all queries, start using INDEXES.
when querying, follow some order in using the indexes also.
like,

SELECT* FROM tablename WHERE (condition with Primary key) and (condition with foreign keys) and (so on);

That means the order of using indexes in a query is also matters.

Try this.